# Rails validations: Multi-field uniqueness: Unnecessary queries in the database

Tags: postgresql, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, unique-constraint

I have a Rails 4.2/Ruby 2.2 application, where I have a **users** table and a **servers** table. A server "belongs to" a user (foreign keyed by **user_id**), and a server name must be unique to a particular user.   It looks like this in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255)
);

CREATE TABLE servers (
  id integer NOT NULL, 
  name character varying(255),
  user_id integer NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE servers ADD CONSTRAINT servers_user_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT; 

ALTER TABLE servers ADD PRIMARY KEY (user_id, name);
```

This SQL will prevent me from adding a server referring to an invalid user, and it will prevent a given user from using a server name more than once.

The Rails models look something like this:

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :servers
end

class Server << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "user_id"

  validates :must_have_unique_name_and_user_id, on: :create

  def must_have_unique_name_and_user_id
    name_count = Server.where(user_id: user_id, name: name).count
    if name_count > 0
      errors[:base] << "Server name is already taken for name #{name}, and user #{user.name}"
  end
end
```

My problem is that when I run the test suite with code coverage, **must_have_unique_name_and_user_id()** gets called hundreds of times because these two models are foundational to my overall data model. Each one of those validation calls results in a database query to check to see if a server name is unique to a user.

This seems like a lot of unnecessary work just to ensure valid data in Rails for something which the database will not allow no matter what.

Is it possible to structure the Rails validations so that the error message I have in the Rails validation **must_have_unique_name_and_user_id()** is displayed if a user tries to have a duplicated (user_id, name) combination for a server, but such that the Rails validation is not run every single time?

Answer (score 1):

The database is your source of truth for which users and servers appear together, so there's no way Rails can validate that without asking.

You can, however, remove the validation in Rails and leave it to the DB by putting a unique index on `servers.user_id, servers.name`. This will raise an exception if you try to update or create an invalid row, which you'll then have to catch and handle.

So your options are a tradeoff between extra queries and code complexity. My advice: let Rails do the extra queries until you're hitting performance issues.

If this is a problem specific to your test suite (ie, you're trying to get it to run faster), you can try to avoid actually creating objects in tests. Touching the DB is often a large hit compared to doing everything in one process's memory, so if you can build, wire, and use the objects without saving them, you'll probably get a solid speedup.

Comment: One thing I didn't mention is that I use the SQL database for my tests. I don't just use the Ruby schema.rb (e.g. config.active_record.schema_format = :sql). The test suite is at about 700 tests, and takes about 4 minutes to run. It's a bit long for my liking.

Comment: I think this all still applies - did you have a specific followup question?

Comment: I can't avoid touching the database during my tests because I'm not using schema.rb for the tests, and therefore I can't speed things up by avoiding the database.

Comment: Not using `schema.rb` doesn't preclude you from avoiding the DB. Just use `Server.new` anywhere you can get away with it instead of `Server.create`. You only _have_ to touch the DB where you're testing the uniqueness constraint or need to set up complex state for something downstream.